# VBScript ERROR: Type mismatch: 'Range'

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am importing long numbers into Column A in my excel spreadsheet and they keep automatically converting to scientific notation. I am trying to format that whole column as a string.

```
Range("A1:A5000").NumberFormat = "@"
```

ERROR: Type mismatch:'Range'

While I am at it, is there any way to specify the entire column no matter how long or short it 
will actually be?

Answer (score 2):

`Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"` will do the job.

Note that `.Range` will refer to `ActiveSheet`, i.e. if you're in a Chart it fail.

Therefore, better specify, which sheet you want to format, e.g. `Sheets("yourSheet").Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "@"`.